# What is this stock-certificate-like document and is it worth anything?

Tags: share-certificate

I found this paper document amongst my things when moving out of my childhood home. I'm trying to determine if this means there is an account somewhere in my name that holds stock in "I C Industries".

[image: stock certificate]

From what I've found online the company was passed around a few different times and may have ended up as part of Pepsi.

I tried contacting Janney Montgomery Scott, Inc but the general email address I contacted. had no idea what I was talking about.

I'm fully resigned to this being a lost cause, either since this never was a real certificate or because it's too far gone to figure out.

Comment: "Stockholders Of America" sounds like an investment club or something of that sort -- if not a scam. This is NOT a share certificate in the company that was typed onto the form. Websearch for S of A finds nothing.

Comment: This looks like something included in a "Congratulations" card sent to your parents when you were born. Whoever it was may indeed have bought the 10 share of I C Industries stock on our behalf, but this piece of paper isn't proof of that. You should contact the person who sent it (if possible) and ask them if they have the actual shares, or if there is a brokerage account where they kept the shares.

Comment: Also if the original benefactor is unavailable you may want to check your birth state's unclaimed funds if he/she placed it in your name. Share ownership can lapse (not voting in proxies, not cashing dividend checks,.etc) which would then be sent to the owner's last address of record state's unclaimed funds.